# Find the original cost of order?

Tags: word-problem

How can i find the original cost of an order?

For example,

If the store I go to offers a 15% discount on all order but I purchase $272 of stuff after the discount, how can I found out what my original cost would be before/without the discount?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. A question like this that shows no work of your own is likely to  attract downvotes and votes to close rather than answers. In this case I answered anyway since it's a common question and may be a teachable moment for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do these problems is to think of percentage change as multiplication. In this case
$$
0.85 \times \text{ original cost} = \$272
$$
so
$$
\text{ original cost} = \frac{\$272}{0.85} = \cdots .
$$
What you can't do is just add $15\%$ of $\$272$ to $\$272$ .

Comment: So the answer is 320. my mistake was: "What you can't do is just subtract 15% of $272 from  $272" thanks for the help!

Comment: @JackMasso You're welcome. And responding to your comment, I fixed the "what you can't do", replacing subtract by add.